# Jupyter notebook for html, css, javascript and php?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Just like jupyter notebook for python supports instant result preview and code cells, is there a software which is similar to it which supports html, css, javascript and php? I should also be able to write notes.

If I write `console.log('hello')` in a cell, it should output the result under the code.

If I write `<h1 style = 'color:red'>Hello</h1>`, it should output Hello in red below the code.

Comment: Check out https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/responsive-css-grid

Comment: @Framester jsfiddle is not like jupyter notebook, it is just an online ide.